# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, mern

```
const getToken = (userId, token) => {
  22 |   getmeToken(userId, token).then((info) => {
  23 |     console.log("INFO COMING", info);
> 24 |     if (info.error) {
  25 |      setInfo({ ...info, error: info.error });
  26 |     } else {
  27 |       const clientToken = info.clientToken;
```

What is meant by Unhandled rejection, cannot read properties of undefined??.

I have defined the **error** and also assigned a value for it, below is the code of `useState`

```
  const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    loading: false,
    success: false,
    clientToken: null,
    error:"",
    instance: {},
  });
```

As per the above code, I have defined and assigned the value for error, then why is the browser still showing **cannot read properties of undefined**.
Can anyone please clarify this?

**getmeToken** function code is below

```
export const getmeToken = (userId, token) => {
    return fetch(` ${API}/payent/gettoken/${userId}`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: There might be some problems in the `getmeToken` function. Can we see the code?

Comment: To point out, info is a local variable inside the promise `then`. I hope you know that

Comment: Info in the scope of that function is the one received from getmeToken not the one from useState.

Comment: @Vid Yeah, I have edited and added it, please have a look.

Comment: Unhandled rejection means an error occurred and since you didn't add a catch block it was not caught, and "can't read properties of undefined" means that you are trying to access the parameters of an undefined object, what is displayed when info is printed to console?.

Comment: @aim97 I am getting undefined when I try to print the info.

Comment: @TusharShahi I didn't clearly get your point, or what you are trying to explain.

Comment: you must return in catch something `.catch(err => {return {info: {error:err}}})`

Comment: Try printing the response and check if the data you want is actually there, if not then it's a back-end problem.

Comment: As already mentioned: info in `getmeToken(userId, token).then((info) => ...` has nothing to do with `info` in the state. The error happens in the API call and is not propagated into the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the output of the `getmeToken` function. Then, you can use `info?.error` instead of `info.error` to handle this error.

**Edit**:
Check the `${API}/payent/gettoken/${userId}` url again. I think `/payent/` is incorrect (`/payment/` is correct)

Comment: If I make the changes as per your answer, I am getting the same Unhandled rejection, cannot read properties of Undefined ( read 'clientToken').

Comment: So, info is undefined (in info.clientToken).

Comment: Please send me console.log(response) result. @AravindaKS

Comment: I updated my answer. check it again. @AravindaKS

Comment: Yes, Thank you, the URL was wrong. @Milad Jafari